# help with readied action

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, readied-action, action-economy

We roll a new initiative each turn to make it more random.

The scenario: the fighter readies to attack the creature when it moves into his range.  The creature moves but doesn't reach the fighter.
on the next turn, we roll initiative and the creature goes first: he moves into range and the fighter uses his action from the last round for his readied action, which is a reaction. Now the creature attacks the fighter.

Is it now the fighter's turn to go again? Since the first attack was a reaction from the previous round, does the fighter attack twice in the round and get his reaction back since he now had his turn?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. This seems like it could be a question about how rerolling initiative every round affects readied actions, but the specific questions in the last paragraph either look like they'd apply without it, or rely on incorrect assumptions about how reactions work, and I'm not sure which one is Your Question.

Comment: Why is the question tagged "house rules"? Rolling initiative every round is a variant rule described in the DMG.

Comment: @ZwiQ Rolling initiative every round is only part of it.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the Players handbook we can see this section on the Ready action:

> Ready
>
> Sometimes you want to get the jump on a foe or wait for a particular circumstance >before you act. To do so, you can take the Ready action on your turn, which lets >you act using your reaction before the **start of your next turn**.

Now according to your scenario the fighter has correctly used the ready. It occurred **before** their turn. It does not matter that their turn is directly after a Ready action. In the eyes of the game they are not getting 2 attacking in 1 round. Rather their round has not finished until their turn comes again. Therefore they have made 1 reaction from the previous round and on their turn it is now the start of their round, meaning they are allowed to take an action and a reaction.

While rounds may seem like they should only encompass the full set of player turns (only from the start of the initiative order to the end and not after), this just does not work. If a round was to do that, then whoever had the lowest initiative (using the normal initiative rules) would never be able to make a reaction attack from a ready action. Therefore why should changing initiative make a difference here. The answer is it shouldn't. It is a new round for them. Just as if a player with the lowest initiative got to use their reaction when the top of the initiative order was reached. they don't lose an action or reaction just because they were unlucky enough to have their turn last.